# Javascript dg.cs for Digital goods showing lightbox as well as paypal window with some error

Tags: paypal

Two windows (one lightbox window and another paypal main page window) simultaneously open up when I click Continue to paypal in my website (Please Note: at this time I have Token from paypal and onclicking this button I redirect user to:

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=" + resp.Token+"&useraction=commit");
```

and I call javascript function as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: "PP_btn", expType: "mini" });
    });
</script>
```

The paypal window opening shows error: "**Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information**"

Don't understand what the problem is. Let me know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To open the PayPal lightbox window, here is the simplest way:

```
<form action='checkout.php' METHOD='POST'>
    <input type='image' name='paypal_submit' id='paypal_submit'  src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Pay with PayPal'/>
</form>

<!-- Add Digital goods in-context experience. Ensure that this script is added before the closing of html body tag -->

<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>

    var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(
    {
        trigger: 'paypal_submit',
        expType: 'instant'
         //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
    });

</script>
```